# Program runs infinitely on typing ctrl C instead of stopping in c++

Tags: c++, windows, loops, infinite-loop, cin

I have the following code. It runs infinitely after typing `ctrl + c` and executes the default section of code.

```
// Program to build a simple calculator using switch Statement
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char oper;
    float num1, num2;
    while(true){
        cout << "Enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ";
        cin >> oper;
        cout << "Enter two numbers: " << endl;
        cin >> num1 >> num2;

        switch (oper) {
            case '+':
                cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                cout << num1 << " * " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                cout << num1 << " / " << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2;
                break;
            default:
                // operator is doesn't match any case constant (+, -, *, /)
                cout << "Error! The operator is not correct";
                break;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result after typing `ctrl + c` is as shown in the image.
[image]

So my question is: is it normal behavior in c++? If it is, then, how may we interpret it?

Comment: Did you compile with exceptions turned off?  The Ctrl+C should have generated an exception, and since you don't have any exception handling that should have killed your program.

Comment: Check returned values of the cin.opetstor>>.

Comment: @MarkRansom there's nothing here that will throw exceptions

Answer (score 5):

If you want to capture CTRL-C in windows, you cannot capture it like linux by `signal()`. `signal()` does not handle `SIGINT` correctly in windows. You need to use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` for this purpose.

If you don't set handler, application
***may decide to ignore CTRL-C***. CTRL-BREAK is always a signal, but CTRL-C
maybe be not:

> CTRL+BREAK is always treated as a signal, but typical CTRL+C behavior
> can be changed in three ways that prevent the handler functions from
> being called:
>
> 1- The **SetConsoleMode** function can disable the **ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT** mode for a console's input buffer, so CTRL+C is reported as keyboard
> input rather than as a signal.
>
> 2- Calling **SetConsoleCtrlHandler** with the NULL and TRUE arguments causes the calling process to ignore CTRL+C signals. This attribute is
> inherited by child processes, but it can be enabled or disabled by any
> process without affecting existing processes.
>
> 3- If a **console process is being debugged** and CTRL+C signals have not been disabled, the system generates a **DBG_CONTROL_C** exception. This
> exception is raised only for the benefit of the debugger, and an
> application should never use an exception handler to deal with it. If
> the debugger handles the exception, an application will not notice the
> CTRL+C, with one exception: alertable waits will terminate. If the
> debugger passes the exception on unhandled, CTRL+C is passed to the
> console process and treated as a signal, as previously discussed.

Here is the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) document.

Answer (score -4):

Pressing ^C at a terminal causes the kernel to send the SIGINT signal to all processes in the foreground process group of the session controlled by the terminal. In the case that you are running the process in a terminal emulator, sending ^C on the master end causes the foreground processes on the slave end to receive SIGINT.

This behaviour is configurable via the tcsetattr system call.

By default, a process that receives SIGINT will immediately terminate, though a process can choose to ignore or handle this signal. Stay blessed

Comment: You're describing UNIX / POSIX behavior. Does any of this apply on Windows?

Comment: Although OP did not specify that they are using Microsoft Windows, this is apparent from the screenshot that OP posted in the question. If you are unsure which operating system OP is using and you intend to post a OS-specific answer, then you should at least specify in your answer which operating system your answer refers to. Also, once you have 50 reputation points, you can post a comment to the question asking OP for clarification which operating system the question applies to.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have edited the question myself, by adding the "windows" tag.